# JQuery multiple selector issue

Tags: jquery

So basically I have this:

```
<div id="menu" class="menu">
 <ul>
    <li><a href="#">REGISTRAR</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="situation1.php">student</a></li>
            <li><a href="situation2.php">grades</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
 </ul>
```

```
<div id="principal" class="principal">
 <div id="opt"  class="opt">
        <ul id="opt-btn">
            <li >
                <a href="something1.php" id="reserved1" class="btn"></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="something2.php" id="reserved2" class="btn"> </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

I would like to know how to select with jquery all  tags from both the divs so when I click on them takes me to that particular file. Before I had this: $(".menu, a").click(function() but when I add the class principal it didn't work. Help will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: the above HTML are both missing closures, please be more clear.

Comment: `$(".menu,.principal").find('a');`

Comment: Try `class="menu principal"`

Answer (score 3):

jQuery's query syntax is the same as CSS selector syntax. I think this is what you're trying to accomplish:

```
$('#menu a, #principal a')
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML :

```
<div id="principal" class="menu">
...
</div>

<div id="principal" class="menu principal">
...
</div>
```

Keep the `principal` class only if it's necessary for other reasons.

jQuery:

```
$(".menu a").on('click', function() {...});
```

This will allow you to add as many menus as you like without changing the selector.